# Vuetify v-select disabling items without manipulating the object

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I've read anywhere even in the official docs and I only found that `v-select`'s items can only be disabled by setting the object's `disable` to true like this...

```
{text: 'text1', disabled: true}, //disabled
{text: 'text2', disabled: false}, //enabled
{text: 'text2', disabled: true}, //disabled
```

But in my case, since I am having a dynamic form where in users can create a new form by clicking a button.

Are there any way to disable `v-select`'s item directly from the `v-select` tag itself or perhaps there's a slot for it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `v-slot:item` to show your customized `v-list-item` element.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots-item

After that you can control the input and the events inside, so you can disable it,

**for example:**

```
    <v-select :items="[{ name: 'item1', disabled: false }, { name: 'item2', disabled: true }]">
        <template v-slot:item="{ on, item }">
            <v-list-item v-on="on" :disabled="item.disabled">{{ item.name }}</v-list-item>
        </template>
    </v-select>
```